# Create user with sdk from AD in Dynamics CRM '13

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am attempting to create a simple application for creating users in our on-prem Dynamics 2013 CRM installation. Right now, we create a user in AD then go to CRM and import the user by entering the AD username and domain in the CRM username field. We then manually enter the additional user properties. Currently, I have my app creating the AD users but, being new to CRM, I am stumbling about figuring out how to utilize the sdk to add my users in CRM.  Also, I wonder if there is a better way to go about this.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are creating users using an app, aren't you using the SDK?

Comment: I am using the SDK. We use AD for authentication however. So, the user needs to exist and match in both places.

Comment: Ok, then do as AdamV suggests, one thing might be that not all AD users should be in CRM but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with this from the online MSDN reference:
[Sample: Create an on-premises user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj602984.aspx)